# Why no dead code warning after return statement?

Tags: scala, return

Can anyone explain why the method below is compiling without any error message? I expected a dead code warning or something like that. Is there a reason why it compiles?

```
def somethingAfterReturn(): Int = {
   println("That is ok..");
   return 1
   println("WTF is going on here?");
   3
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, try this:

```
$ scala -e 'def somethingAfterReturn(): Int = { println("That is ok.."); return 1; println("WTF is going on here?"); 3 }'
```

no errors, right?

Then, try this:

```
$ scala -Ywarn-dead-code -e 'def somethingAfterReturn(): Int = { println("That is ok.."); return 1; println("WTF is going on here?"); 3 }'
```

By default, Scala ignore [unreachable code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code).

Comment: But why is deadcode allowed to be written if it's finally ignored? What for this kind of "feature"?

Comment: @MarcinSanecki In Scala you should avoid using return statements, thus it is less important than in Java to spot unreachable code. By disabling this check you can save compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler allows this because it is syntactically valid.

Comment: Nice... ok. Do you what idea stays behinde this?

Comment: In general the compiler doesn't care simply because for ease of compilation. That means, for efficiency's sake. If it has to keep checking for dead code it will be quite expensive.

Comment: Downvoted because, ... well, it's a poor point: yes, it is *syntatically valid* but the smart compiler's job is to warn you sometimes, when you might fail with something. Unexastive match is syntatically valid too, but compiler will warn you without *some-special-unexastive-flag*.

Comment: `val i: Int = "Hello"` is also syntactically valid, yet it will fail to compile. That's not a good argument.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sees the code after the return will never get executed and so he ignores it ... so i think

Comment: Have you found this in scala documentation?